# Ruby split string into 7 character chunks at each character

Tags: ruby, string, split, character

How can I do the following in ruby:

```
a = 1234567890

Split into strings 7 characters in length at each character:

=> [1234567,2345678,3456789,4567890]
```

Thanks!

Edit: Thank you everyone for all the help. Sorry for not saying what I had attempted (although nothing was close to a solution).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try and why didn't it work? Did you search for solutions? If so, why didn't they help? As is it looks like you're asking us to write code for you, which isn't what SO is for.

Answer (score 2):

```
a.to_s.each_char.each_cons(7).map{|s| s.join.to_i}
# => [1234567, 2345678, 3456789, 4567890]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 1234567890

# Convert to a string, then convert that string
# into an array of characters
chars = a.to_s.chars # => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

slices = []

# Slice the array into groups of 7, with successive indices
chars.each_cons(7) do |cons|
  slices << cons.join # Join each 7-item array into a string and push it
end

p slices # => ["1234567", "2345678", "3456789", "4567890"]
```

The key method you're looking for is [`each_cons`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_cons).

Answer (score 0):

If you fancy using some more obscure Ruby methods then this works too:

```
(0..a.to_s.size-7).map { |i| a.to_s.chars.rotate(i).take(7).join.to_i }
#=> [1234567, 2345678, 3456789, 4567890]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.to_s.scan(/(?=(.{7}))/).map { |arr| arr.first.to_i }
  #=> [1234567, 2345678, 3456789, 4567890]
```

`(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead. `(.{7})` matches the next seven characters in capture group 1. See [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) for how `scan` treats capture groups. We have

```
s = a.to_s
  #=> "1234567890" 
b = s.scan(/(?=(.{7}))/)
  #=> [["1234567"], ["2345678"], ["3456789"], ["4567890"]] 
b.map { |arr| arr.first.to_i }
  #=> [1234567, 2345678, 3456789, 4567890]
```